# How do I format ${date} in Pandoc HTML output?

Tags: pandoc

I have a LaTeX document that I convert to HTML using Pandoc. My template references the `$date$` variable like so:

```html
$if(date)$
<p>$date$</p>
$endif$
```

As usual, the value of `$date$` is the ISO formatted date (e.g., 2022-06-17 for today). I want to format it so that it has a human-readable format, so that I can get this output:

```html
<p>17 Jun 2022</p>
```

Usually, one can achieve this using format strings (for the above example: `%d %b %Y`). Is there a way to do that for the Pandoc's output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple Lua filter can achieve this.
The following filter code is adapted from [Setting the date in the metadata](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html#setting-the-date-in-the-metadata) from the Pandoc documentation.

```lua
-- filters/date-format.lua
function Meta(meta)
  if meta.date then
    local format = "(%d+)-(%d+)-(%d+)"
    local y, m, d = pandoc.utils.stringify(meta.date):match(format)
    local date = os.time({
      year = y,
      month = m,
      day = d,
    })
    local date_string = os.date("%d %b %Y", date)

    meta.date = pandoc.Str(date_string)
    return meta
  end
end
```

```markdown
---
# test.md
title: My Title
date: 2022-06-18
---
```

```html
<!-- templates/date.html -->
$if(date)$
<p>$date$</p>
$endif$
```

Compile with the command `pandoc --data-dir=. --template=date --lua-filter=date-format.lua test.md -o test.html`.
The output should be `<p>18 Jun 2022</p>`.

Comment: Had a small problem executing it with `--data-dir`. This did it for me:

`pandoc --template ./templates/date.html --lua-filter ./filters/date-format.lua test.md -o test.html`

Answer (score 0):

Here is another method you can use, assuming you are running pandoc in a Linux / Unix environment, and you are trying to get the date to dynamically fill in the HTML header when you compile the document.

I am using a Markdown input document, but I believe this method should work with other types of input that support the pandoc document header (https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-yaml_metadata_block).

For context, using the https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#templates

with my input file `document.md`

```markdown
---
title: "Document title goes here"
date: $date
---

...

...
```

note the variable `$date` referenced here

Compile with a command like this

```bash
pandoc document.md \
-V "date:$(date '+%Y-%m-%d')" \
--output=document.html \
--from=markdown \
--to=html
```

The output `document.html` will contain contents like this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
...
<body>
<header id="title-block-header">
<h1 class="title">Document title goes here</h1>
<p class="date">2024-02-14</p>
</header>
...
```

as you can see, the date "2024-02-14" was inserted into the HTML output